# Flask-Whooshee a error 'WhoosheeQuery' object has no attribute '_join_entities'

Tags: python, flask, flask-whooshee

this is my model based flask-sqlalchemy

```
@whooshee.register_model('title','content')
class PostModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    create_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.now)
    read_count = db.Column(db.Integer,default=0)
    board_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("board.id"))
    author_id = db.Column(db.String(100),db.ForeignKey("front_user.id"),nullable=False)
```

```
@bp.route('/search/')
def index_search():
    q = request.args.get('q','')
    print(q)
    if q == '':
        flash('enter key words','warning')
        return redirect(url_for('front.index'))
    result = PostModel.query.whooshee_search(q).order_by(PostModel.create_time.desc()).all()
    print(result)
    return render_template('front/front_search.html',result=result)
```

if self._join_entities and isinstance(self._join_entities[0], Mapper):
AttributeError: 'WhoosheeQuery' object has no attribute '_join_entities'

could you tell me how to solve the problem？

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best fix but since you're only using whooshee search on just `PostModel`, comment out this part in the `flask_whooshee.py` module.

```py
if self._join_entities and isinstance(self._join_entities[0], Mapper):
    # SQLAlchemy >= 0.8.0
    entities.update(set([x.entity for x in self._join_entities]))
else:
    # SQLAlchemy < 0.8.0
    entities.update(set(self._join_entities))
```

Answer (score 0):

comment out this part in the flask_whooshee.py module. it works for me.

```
if self._join_entities and isinstance(self._join_entities[0], Mapper):
# SQLAlchemy >= 0.8.0
entities.update(set([x.entity for x in self._join_entities]))
```

else:
# SQLAlchemy < 0.8.0
entities.update(set(self._join_entities))